# Supervisor asks to create fake feedbacks

Tags: ethics

So today my supervisor at work asked me for a second time to periodically create gmail and facebook accounts and post fake positive feedback and reviews for our eshop.  I added this in my Todo list although this is against my moral ethics and I'd like to find a way to cope with this request. 
PS. Our site is a legit business, selling good products and in no way I incline that our company has ever tried to mislead clients in any kind of way. (other than this request for fake reviews of course ).

How would you politely handle this kind of situation?

Comment: There is no way we can decide for you whether you should violate your personal ethics to keep am job. There is no magic wand we can wave to make this situation go away, and only you can decide if you want to do it.

Comment: I do not want you to decide for me  I would like an opinion on how would you handle it..

Comment: "Our site is not cheating of course and in no way I incline that our company tries to mislead clients in any kind (other than these fake reviews of course ).". Guess what - your site IS cheating. What you wrote is like saying "I've never stolen anything, other than that time I took money that didn't belong to me."

Comment: No I insist. We are a legit business which has never cheated . These reviews are not written or published yet

Comment: What about suggesting ways to improve your actual products/services so that the real reviews are good instead ? If your products/service are bad, you won't be able to cope with all the real negative comments let alone have enough time to post a sufficient amount of fake positive feedback to balance those out. This is at best an exercise in futility, and a very unethical one. Use this time to improve the company instead.

Comment: @skinnb1s Then I withdraw that. Your company not not cheated yet. But your supervisor wants it to cheat and is trying to cheat.

Comment: I totally agree with that!

Comment: @skinnb1s  How do you know that you are the first person asked to create such reviews.  If your supervisor is happy to make such requests I'd say there is a good chance that other people have been asked (and/or your supervisor has also been doing it).

Comment: If you claim to truly have morals and ethics (and desire to keep making that claim), the answer is simple. Refuse. Otherwise, they're compromised.

Comment: It is not exactly honest but it is also better common.  Something you need to decide.

Comment: It's your supervisor asking you to cheat. Does your company actually support this? You might consider some careful enquiry in that direction. And mentioning potential desastrous consequences might help your case.

Comment: Why is this against your ethics? Not questioning them, but ask this yourself. Also ask this question assuming you had a financial stake in the company. These asnwers should give you constructive feedback to give to management on why this is a bad idea.

Comment: A bit harsh to close this question... But, what you could do is find excuses to refuse. For example, if whatever the review site is find out what you're doing (and they're getting better all the time at it), they'll ban your company from the site altogether.

Comment: Alternatively, if it's just your ethics you're worried about, you could always give the types of reviews that are positive but help nobody and will most likely be ignored, e.g. "5 stars! Great Product!" then several others like it in quick succession - though be aware, this could make it easy for the review site to spot it and wind up getting your company banned as per my previous comment

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. I confronted my supersvisor today about this issue analyzing the obvious dangers (google bans etc) of such a move, presentating an email campaign to prompt our clients to post a review and also stating how unethical and wrong I find this kind of solution. He accepted my idea and we are working on it.Thanks again

Comment: If you're in the US, beware that the FTC says this sort of thing is clearly *illegal*, not just unethical (see https://www.ftc.gov/tips-advice/business-center/guidance/ftcs-endorsement-guides-what-people-are-asking). And they do enforce it: https://www.ftc.gov/news-events/press-releases/2016/07/warner-bros-settles-ftc-charges-it-failed-adequately-disclose-it

Answer (score 4):

Let me give you some options:

- Flat out refusal is always an option. You might be fired, or your supervisor might just get someone else to do it, or drop the idea. It's possible your supervisor didn't realize how strongly you felt about this, or maybe didn't even realize it's unethical.
- Take Masked Man's route of pointing out the practical difficulties, and possible consequences if the company is caught.
- It's possible your supervisor doesn't represent the general way of thinking in the company. Try talking to someone else in the company. If the company has an ethics officer or a legal officer, talk to them. A company lawyer is obliged not to recommend an illegal course of action.
- If you do end up doing this, make sure you get clear instructions from your supervisor in writing (or email etc.) so you can prove he asked you to do it if necessary.

Comment: Another point to bring up is that it's possible to get black listed from Google if it is found fake reviews were written in an attempt to game the system. Do some research on it and you'll see it's real. Some people get their business black listed on the map site because of fake reviews. It won't completely remove you business but it will put it on the bottom of any algorithm they use to conduct searches/reviews.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could offer to write an email to be sent to the people who bought your products or services that will prompt them to write a review. You could even suggest a promotional deal to offer an incentive to people if they write reviews which could benefit the company in multiple ways by gaining a review, additional revenue, and returning customers. This will keep you from having to write any of the reviews yourself and is better from an ethical standpoint. Good luck!

Comment: This is *illegal* in the US if you don't clearly disclose that the reviewers were paid by the company. See https://www.ftc.gov/tips-advice/business-center/guidance/ftcs-endorsement-guides-what-people-are-asking

Comment: I read the article. I guess my only point would be that they would receive the incentive regardless of the review. You're not paying them to be positive, you're offering an incentive for an honest review. How many mobile applications offer incentives for reviews, or posting to facebook. This would fall in the same category in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

If you like your job and would like to keep your supervisor happy, then do it. If your ethics trump that, then don't but be aware there may be repercussions.

Or compromise by sitting down and seriously thinking about the issue until you have worked out a rationalisation that makes it ok to do.

Personally I would tell him/her to do it themselves, it's not on my job description unless I'm hired to write reviews. But that's not an ethical issue, that's a professional one, I wouldn't polish the floors either unless I'm employed as cleaner.